# IsControl in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a function like .Net's Char.IsControl() in Javascript?
Also, I find it very inconvenient that Javascript doesn't have an official web site like Python, Java and C#. What do you use as reference?

Comment: *"Also, I find it very inconvenient that Javascript doesn't have an official web site like Python, Java and C#"* There's nothing like going to [the specifiation](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Comment: MSDN gives a definition of control characters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18zw7440.aspx so it shouldn't be too difficult to implement a function that does the same thing in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't one. However, JavaScript uses UTF-16 and so you can use the [Unicode definition of a control character](http://unicode.org/glossary/#control_codes) to write your own. That definition is:

> *Control Codes* The 65 characters in the ranges U+0000..U+001F and U+007F..U+009F. Also known as control characters.

Thus:

```
function isControl(ch) {
    var code = ch.charCodeAt(0);
    return ((code >= 0x0000 && code <= 0x001f) || (code >= 0x007f && code <= 0x009f));
}
```

Or as a regexp:

```
var isControlRex = /[\u0000-\u001F\u007F-\u009F]/;
function isControl(ch) {
    return isControlRex.test(ch);
}
```

I use [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) as a reference. Also the Mozilla Developer Network's (what we used to call the MDC) [JavaScript pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript).